# Python -- TypeError: int object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, int, tuples, typeerror, accessor

I've got next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "DungeonGame.py", line 92, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                        
    possible = possibleMoves(locations["player"])                                                                                                                                                                                    
  File "DungeonGame.py", line 65, in possibleMoves                                                                                                                                                                                   
      if player[0][0] == 0: 
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is my code:

```
def possibleMoves(player):
    options = ["RIGHT", "LEFT", "UP", "DOWN"]

    if player[0][0] == 0:
        options.remove("LEFT")
    elif player[0][0] == 4:
        options.remove("RIGHT")    
    elif player[0][1] == 0:
        options.remove("DOWN")
    elif player[0][1] == 4:
       options.remove("UP")

    return options 

...

locations = {"monster" : (1, 2), "door" : (3, 2), "player" : (4, 1)}
possible = possibleMoves(locations["player"])
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: `locations["player"]` is the value `(4, 1)`. `(4, 1)[0]` is `4`. What do you expect `4[0]` to mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the reason why you get the error:

```
player[0][0] == (4, 1)[0][0] == 4[0]
```

You pass `locations["player"]` to `possibleMoves(player)`, so `player == locations["player"] == (4, 1)`.

Comment: Huh, I didn't see that. Thanks for the help!